# gradient under UIBezierPath animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-graphics, core-animation

I need help with core animation on iOS

I have the following view

[image]

I need to animate curve appearance from left to right. This step was achieved by `animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"`, it works and all is fine.

Also I need to animate the gradient appearance under the curve, which goes from left to right along with the curve appearance

Here is the cut from reference video about the appearance I need to achieve
 [image: source video gif cut]

How can I achieve this?

Layers and paths I have:

(1) gradient curve line - uishapelayer
colored gradient - cagradient layer having (1) as mask

(2) closed path layer - path along the (1) curve, but with [path closePath];
gray gradient - cagradient having (2) as mask

(3) animationLayer - layer, added as [self.layer addSublayer:animationLayer]
(3) has colored gradien and gray gradient as sublayers

initWithFrame:

```
    _animationLayer = [CALayer new];
    _animationLayer.frame = frame;
    _animationLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_animationLayer];

    _path = [self characteristicsGraph:frame];

    _pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    _pathLayer.frame = frame;
    _pathLayer.path = _path.CGPath;
    _pathLayer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
    _pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    _pathLayer.lineWidth = lineW;


    _fillPathLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    _fillPathLayer.frame = frame;
    _fillPathLayer.path = [self closePath:_path].CGPath;
    _fillPathLayer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
    _fillPathLayer.fillColor = [color CGColor];
    _fillPathLayer.masksToBounds = YES;


    _fillGradient = [self gradient:frame];
    _fillGradient.frame = frame;
    _fillGradient.mask = _fillPathLayer;

    _lineGradient = [self lineGradient:frame];
    _lineGradient.frame = frame;
    _lineGradient.mask = _pathLayer;

    [_animationLayer addSublayer:_fillGradient];
    [_animationLayer addSublayer:_lineGradient];
```

pathLayer animation (animates colored gradient appearance):

```
self.currentAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
self.currentAnimation.fromValue = @(0);
self.currentAnimation.toValue = @(1);
self.currentAnimation.duration = .5;
[self.pathLayer addAnimation:self.currentAnimation forKey:animationKey];
```

Gray gradient is static, can't animate it. 
Will be grateful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a mask layer for the gradient layer - just make it a rectangle that expands as the line animates.

The other problem I noticed if you want to be 100% true to the video is that your gradient will need to be angled along the trend of the chart - notice their chart trends up, and the gradient angle matches.

Comment: Yes, final solution is to make parent layer - the one which contains all required layers - animatable with `bounds.size.width` property. 
Gradient layer is layer with 3 colors and 3 control points which is masked by curve path layer. Yeah, thanks for you suggestion. It helped me.

There is another problem - the big circle which is "drawing" the line. Can't animate it for now, it's layer animation is not synched with the rest animations. But it's a different question.

Comment: Obvious question - but does the circle animation code match in duration and easing curve? Does it have a matching start and end value? I just recently did a project like this where a dot was animating a line, and it requires precision for sure.

Comment: I start both animations in one place with the same values. 
one animation - `bounds.size.width` CABasicAnimation for container layer, another one - `position` CAKeyFrame animation. Duration is the same, values are different but comprise one whole figure. Position animation is kind of tailing width animation.

Comment: Try setting the `calculationMode` for both keyframe animations to `kCAAnimationPaced` - this will set the timing for intermediate keyframes to keep a steady pace throughout - MAY help with your alignment issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Value_calculation_modes